# For Loop Prints for the Length of 2 internal lists when I only need 1

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list of xy coords like this:
[[xcoords][ycoords]]
Because my For loop is using the length of the entire list it prints 90 odd results, when in reality I only need half that.

When I try accessing the length of the first half, I get this error:
*index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2*

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapely.geometry
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import descartes    

quality = 7
x = np.linspace(-1,1,quality)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,quality)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
polycoords = [[-1, 1], [-1, 0.5], [0, 0.5], [0, 1]]
clip_poly = shapely.geometry.Polygon(polycoords)


positions = np.vstack([Y.ravel(), X.ravel()])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
polygonbuilding = ax.add_patch(descartes.PolygonPatch(clip_poly, fc='pink', alpha=0.3))

origin = [0,0]


for i in range(len(positions)):
    for j in range(len(positions[i])):
        plt.scatter(*positions[::-1])
        x1 = positions[0][j]
        y1 = positions[1][j]
        line = LineString([origin, (x1, y1)])
        ax.plot(*np.array(line).T, color='none', linewidth=1, solid_capstyle='round')
        if line.intersects(clip_poly) == True:
            ax.plot(*np.array(line).T, color='red', linewidth=1, solid_capstyle='round')
        else:
            ax.plot(*np.array(line).T, color='green', linewidth=1, solid_capstyle='round')
        print (origin, [x1,y1],line.intersects(clip_poly)/2)
        
plt.show()
```

What I get VS What I need (in Red)

[image: What I get VS What I need (in Red)]

Answer (score 0):

it's because you have a dup in your [positions] var, try printing it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapely.geometry
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import descartes    

quality = 7
x = np.linspace(-1,1,quality)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,quality)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
polycoords = [[-1, 1], [-1, 0.5], [0, 0.5], [0, 1]]
clip_poly = shapely.geometry.Polygon(polycoords)


positions = np.vstack([Y.ravel(), X.ravel()])
print(positions)

[[-1.         -1.         -1.         -1.         -1.         -1.
  -1.         -0.66666667 -0.66666667 -0.66666667 -0.66666667 -0.66666667
  -0.66666667 -0.66666667 -0.33333333 -0.33333333 -0.33333333 -0.33333333
  -0.33333333 -0.33333333 -0.33333333  0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.33333333  0.33333333
   0.33333333  0.33333333  0.33333333  0.33333333  0.33333333  0.66666667
   0.66666667  0.66666667  0.66666667  0.66666667  0.66666667  0.66666667
   1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.
   1.        ]
 [-1.         -0.66666667 -0.33333333  0.          0.33333333  0.66666667
   1.         -1.         -0.66666667 -0.33333333  0.          0.33333333
   0.66666667  1.         -1.         -0.66666667 -0.33333333  0.
   0.33333333  0.66666667  1.         -1.         -0.66666667 -0.33333333
   0.          0.33333333  0.66666667  1.         -1.         -0.66666667
  -0.33333333  0.          0.33333333  0.66666667  1.         -1.
  -0.66666667 -0.33333333  0.          0.33333333  0.66666667  1.
  -1.         -0.66666667 -0.33333333  0.          0.33333333  0.66666667
   1.        ]]
```

Comment: They're not dups, rather corresponding x and y values although they may look like it. The structure of the positons list is [[xcoords][ycoords]]. But because they're separated lists within the greater list. The loop runs through the entire length.